# Hibernate OneToMany / ManyToOne results in SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Im having a `OneToMany` / `ManyToOne` relationship between two tables. There is a foreign key in the table `Partition` referencing on the `id` of `Event`. When I call `event.getPartitions()` which should return a list containing all `Partitions` in one `Event`, I get the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax.
```

The `dialect` is set to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and the `driver class` is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

getPartitions:

```
@XmlTransient
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
public Collection<Partition> getPartitions()
{
    return partitions;
}
```

getEvent:

```
@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public Event getEvent()
{
    return event;
}
```

Event:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `event`;
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `img` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `information` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Partition:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `partition`;
CREATE TABLE `partition` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `event_id` (`event_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_partition` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The following queries get exceuted, which also look ok to me:

```
10:44:04,708 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Hibernate: select event0_.id as id1_1_0_, event0_.date as date2_1_0_, event0_.description as descript3_1_0_, event0_.img as img4_1_0_, event0_.information as informat5_1_0_, event0_.location as location6_1_0_, event0_.title as title7_1_0_ from Event event0_ where event0_.id=?
10:44:04,818 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Hibernate: select partitions0_.event_id as event_id6_1_0_, partitions0_.id as id1_2_0_, partitions0_.id as id1_2_1_, partitions0_.active_timestamp as active_t2_2_1_, partitions0_.description as descript3_2_1_, partitions0_.event_id as event_id6_2_1_, partitions0_.position as position4_2_1_, partitions0_.title as title5_2_1_ from Partition partitions0_ where partitions0_.event_id=?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Partition` is [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, change table name to something else (entity name can stay unchanged, just use `@Table` annotation to configure new table name).